# PCA can be used as clustering in stock market?

Tags: pca

I was reading this article https://towardsdatascience.com/stock-market-analytics-with-pca-d1c2318e3f0e and its application to COVID analysis.
I can see that PCA acts as clustering algorithm.

We change a coordinate system from N dimensional user specified to K(=2) dimensional that is driven by eigen vectors. In the COVID section of it, stocks with smallest weights in PCA components were in travel, but weren't those stocks that were the most volatile and as a result they would be explaining the largest chunk of variance? Should not PCA weights be high for most volatile input variables(in this case a sector, i.e. travel)? I understand that high/low weights mean those are most likely in different clusters but what about the magnitude, does the sign of a weight tell me something about the variance of that group?